# TensorFlow eigenvalues and eigenvectors

Tags: python, tensorflow, eigenvalue, eigenvector

I want to use eigenvalues in TensorFlow but it gives wrong eigenvalues/eigenvectors using 'tf.self_adjoint_eig’

In the code below I'm trying to recover the original matrix but the output differs from the original, Any idea, how to fix it?

```
`A11 = tf.constant([[1, 3],[1, 1]], dtype=tf.float32)
[e1, W1] = tf.self_adjoint_eig(A11)
e1 = tf.diag(e1)
A11r = tf.matmul(tf.matmul(W1, e1), tf.matrix_inverse(W1))
A11: [[1. 3.]
[1. 1.]]
A11r: [[0.9999999 0.9999999]
[0.9999999 0.9999999]]`
```

Comment: Your `A11` matrix is not self-adjoint so you shouldn't be using `tf.self_adjoint_eig`.

Comment: Is there any other function in TensorFlow to obtain eigenvalues of non-self-adjoint matrix?

Comment: I don't know of any unfortunately; it's more Numpy territory. What is useful to document here for others is that `tf.self_adjoint_eig` only uses the lower triangular part of the input, so it treats your input matrix as though it is `tf.constant([[1, 1],[1, 1]], dtype=tf.float32)`. The final result is then consistent with this.

Comment: @I-Python what about this function? https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/linalg/eig

Answer (score 0):

If 'tf.self_adjoint_eig’ is not mandatory, you can do it this way:

```
A11 = tf.constant([[1., 3.],[1., 1.]], dtype=tf.float32)
[e1, W1] = tf.linalg.eig(A11)
e1 = tf.linalg.diag(e1)
A11r = tf.matmul(tf.matmul(W1, e1), tf.linalg.inv(W1))
A11: [[1. 3.]
[1. 1.]]
A11r: [[0.9999999 0.9999999]
[0.9999999 0.9999999]]
```

try putting  tf.linalg.function_name()
Here are the results compared to yours.

```
Input: A11
Output: <tf.Tensor: shape=(2, 2), dtype=float32, numpy=
array([[1., 3.],
       [1., 1.]], dtype=float32)>

Input: A11r
Output: <tf.Tensor: shape=(2, 2), dtype=complex64, numpy=
array([[1.0000001+0.j, 3.0000005+0.j],
       [1.       +0.j, 1.       +0.j]], dtype=complex64)>
```

> Here are what I'm getting as errors, and check to see for 'import
> tensorflow as tf'
>
> 1. AttributeError: module 'tensortlow' has no
>    attribute 'self_adjoint_eig'
> 2. AttributeError: module 'tensorflow'
>    has no attribute 'diag'
> 3. AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no
>    attribute 'matrix_inverse'

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).